# Wijmo and jQuery

Tags: jquery, wijmo

I've recently added Wijmo controls to a test website I've been using.

I've found that my jQuery was throwing errors, as if jQuery had been added to the page twice.

If I commented out my jQuery reference the errors disappeared.

So it seems that by including a Wijmo control on my page, it was somehow automatically including jQuery.

My problem is, when implementing Wijmo controls on existing websites, on some pages but not others, some using master pages, some maintained by others...etc this may be overlooked, or someone may remove a Wijmo control at a later date and forget to include jQuery back into the page...etc

Is there a way to stop Wijmo from including jQuery, so that I can just use my normal reference?

Answer (score 0):

Wijmo controls are jQuery based controls so you cannot stop them from using jQuery. However, you may resolve this issue by adding references of your custom JS after C1 controls and remove the jQuery/jQueryUI references.

If the custom JS is added before C1 controls, then jQuery reference of C1 Control will overwrite previous jQuery object resulting in various errors.

Comment: I don't want to stop Wijmo from using jQuery. I want to be able to reference jQuery separately from Wijmo at all times.

Answer (score 0):

From the Wijimo docs the header declarations that you need are

```
<!--jQuery References-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--Theme-->
<link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/aristo/jquery-wijmo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--Wijmo Widgets CSS-->
<link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20132.8.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--Wijmo Widgets JavaScript-->
<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.all.3.20132.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20132.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure the head reference you are using is not one that includes jQuery within it. In the above case they are reference seperately but if you downloaded the js files or are referencing a different CDN you have have a pre-minified combined js file.